# How to suppress LAN connection messages

Tags: networking, connection, lan

I have ubuntu 14.4 running with no LAN cable connected, on a user fixed user application. The system powers up starting the user-application then overlaying with a message telling the LAN is not connected. How can I suppress this message. Even the LAN cable is not there I still want the LAN to connect, when cable is inserted. But the user have no value seeing the message when no cable is there.

Please where- and how to tell the LAN connection function to be quiet.